# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Agent(#70150138059920) expected, got {"id"=>1, "name"=>"Sebastien", "phone_number"=>"345123900"} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70150038272680)):
```

I haven't figured out why.

agent.rb:

```
belongs_to :management
```

management.rb:

```
has_one :agent

accepts_nested_attributes_for :agent, reject_if: proc { |attr| attr['name'].blank? && attributes['phone_number'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

edit.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mb-12>
    <v-form :model='management' ref="managementForm">
     <v-text-field
        v-model='management.agent.name'
        name="name">
     </v-text-field>
     <v-text-field
        v-model='management.agent.phone_number'
        name="number">
     </v-text-field>
     <v-btn @click.prevent='submit'>Save</v-btn>
    </v-form>
   </v-card>
 </template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
      management {
       agent: {
        name: ""
        phone_number: ""
       }
      }
    }
   methods: {
     submit() {
        if (this.$refs.managementForm.validate()) {

            this.$axios.put('/management.json', { management: this.management })
            .then(response => {
            });
        }
        else {
          this.$axios.post('/managements.json', { management: this.management })
            .then(response => {
            });
        }
    }
  }
```

management_controller.rb:

```
def update
  @management = current_management
  render json: { errors: @management.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity unless current_user.management.update_attributes(management_params)
end

private

def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(agent: %i(id name phone_number))
end
```

Comment: We need more information. What have you done to debug this? See "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Answer (score 4):

I made a mistake in `management_params`. I permitted `agent` but it had to be `agent_attributes` because, with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, it looks for attributes with the model name:

```
def management_params
  params.require(:company).permit(agent_attributes: %i(id name phone_number))
end
```

Comment: This sounds like a comment stuck into an answer. Is this supposed to be the answer you intend to select? If so, it's not well written so please flesh it out. Proper formatting is important, as is using correct grammar.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the exact code which solved my problem. 
I read about accepts_nested_attributes_for and I figureout that permit params had to include attributes so this is how I solved my problem